# Get IDs of similar rows by criteria

Tags: postgresql

I basically want to query this table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id, thing, price, type);
AS VALUES 
  (1, 'apple', 1.00, 'fruit'),
  (2, 'orang', 1.00, 'fruit'),
  (3, 'banan', 1.00, 'fruit'),
  (4, 'potat', 2.00, 'veg'),
  (5, 'carro', 2.00, 'veg'),
  (6, 'onion', 2.00, 'veg');
```

I want to grab the ids of records with the same attributes (in this case, price and type) so `1, 2, 3` and `4, 5, 6`.

I don't want to have to specify the `$1.00` or `fruit` values, just group by whatever shows up in those columns, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the aggregate function `array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) for this purpose.

> ```
> select price, type, array_agg(id) ids
> from   tbl
> group by price, type
> ```
>
> ```
> price | type  | ids    
> ----: | :---- | :------
>  1.00 | fruit | {1,2,3}
>  2.00 | veg   | {4,5,6}
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d154ae58d2395d6f0a994828120d683e)*

Comment: `array_agg`!! Doesn't show up in most resources for grouping in aggregate. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to help